# Does std::set still sort when elements are wrapped in smart pointers?

Tags: c++, c++11

Granted there is a class with an overloaded `operator<`...

```
class Rectangle {
    // ...
    const inline bool operator< (const Rectangle &rhs) const {
        return x < rhs.x || (x == rhs.x && y < rhs.y);
    }
}
```

...does a `set` still use this overload when the elements are wrapped in a smart pointer?

```
std::multiset<std::shared_ptr<Rectangle>> elements;
```

Comment: No, you have to write your own comparator function.

Comment: @KerrekSB but it does sort by pointer, just not by the internal object, `shared_ptr` has it's own `<`

Comment: @aaronman: You're answering a different question than KerrekSB.

Comment: @Mehrdad I know what's going on, i'm just saying there is nothing wrong with using a multiset that stores `shared_ptrs`

Comment: @aaronman: I know you know what's going on, but what you're saying is orthogonal to KerrekSB's comment. (You said "but", yet "but" doesn't make sense because you're talking about different things...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`shared_ptr<T>` is designed as a drop-in replacement for `T*`, so it behaves like:

```
std::multiset<Rectangle*> elements;
```

Namely, it will sort by memory address.

If you want to use the underlying `operator<`, you will need to specify a comparator that indirects and makes the comparison: `[p,q]{*p < *q}`

Answer (score 7):

Actually, this is subtle, but you do **not** just want to add a custom comparator to that code.

You need to choose from **one** of these options for the code to make sense:

1. Use `boost::ptr_multiset<Rectangle>` (recommended)
2. Use `std::multiset<std::shared_ptr<const Rectangle>, YourCustomComparator>`

Otherwise, you will be able to modify the keys while they're inside the map (they won't be `const`), which is horrible and will lead you into undefined behavior.

Comment: Or option 3: don't modify the keys. :)  But I agree, const-correctness is a useful safety feature.